# How can I pass multiple values for a single parameter into the API url in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework, arguments

I have made a filter API like this:

```
localhost/api/allpackages?price_min=700&price_max=900&destination=Spain&new_activity=Swimming&tour_type=Group%20Tour&featured=true&fix_departure=true
```

But according to new changes, I should be able to filter like this:

```
localhost/api/allpackages?destination=Spain&destination=Japan&destination=Thailand....featured=true...
```

There can be multiple values for a single parameter, because user can now click the checkboxes on the frontend. How can I achieve this?

My models:

```
class Package(models.Model):
    operator = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    destination = models.ForeignKey(Destination, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    package_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    duration = models.IntegerField(default=5)
    discount = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="15% OFF")
    discounted_price = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    savings = models.IntegerField(default=230)
    tour_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=TOUR_TYPE, default='Group Tour')
    new_activity = models.ManyToManyField(NewActivity)
    accommodation = models.CharField(max_length=255,default='Guest House & Hotel')
    transport = models.CharField(max_length=150, default='Flight')
    age_range = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='6 to 79 years old')
    fix_departure = models.BooleanField(default=False)
....
...
```

My views:

```
class AllPackageAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    filterset_class = PackageFilter
    
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        new_activity = self.request.query_params.get('new_activity', None)
        destination = self.request.query_params.get('destination', None)
        if new_activity is not None:
            if destination is not None:
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination, new_activity__title=new_activity)
            else:
                return Package.objects.filter(new_activity__title=new_activity)
        elif destination is not None:
            if new_activity is not None:
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination, new_activity__title=new_activity)
            else:
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination)
        else:
            return Package.objects.all()
```

My filter:

```
class PackageFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   price = filters.RangeFilter()

   class Meta:
      model = Package
      fields = ['price','featured', 'fix_departure',
                'tour_type',]
```

My serializers:

```
class PackageSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  
    class Meta:
        model = Package
        fields = ['id', 'operator','destination', 'package_name', 'duration', 'featured', 'price', 'discount', 'discounted_price',
                       'tour_type','new_activity', 'accommodation', 'transport', 'age_range',
                  'savings', 'fix_departure', 'rating', 'image', 'date_created', ]
        # fields = '__all__'
        depth = 1
```

I have done this but now no data are shown. The get list is empty. I used `get_queryset(self)` as a function and now `self.request.GET.get` for querying.

My updated view:

```
class AllPackageAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    filterset_class = PackageFilter

def get_queryset(self): 
    new_activity = self.request.GET.get('new_activity', None)
    destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", "")
    destination_values = destination.split(",")
    if new_activity is not None:
        if destination is not None:
            return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination_values, new_activity__title=new_activity)
        else:
            return Package.objects.filter(new_activity__title=new_activity)
    elif destination is not None:
        if new_activity is not None:
            return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination_values, new_activity__title=new_activity)
        else:
            return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination_values)
    else:
        return Package.objects.all()
```

My solution:

```
def get_queryset(self):
# def get(self, request, format=None, *args, **kwargs):

    new_activity = self.request.GET.get('new_activity',None)
    destination = self.request.GET.get("destination",None)
    tour_type = self.request.GET.get("tour_type",None)
    if new_activity is not None:
        new_activity = self.request.GET.get('new_activity', "")
        new_activity_values = new_activity.split(",")
        if destination is not None:
            destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", "")
            destination_values = destination.split(",")
            if tour_type is not None:
                tour_type = self.request.GET.get("tour_type", "")
                tour_type_values = tour_type.split(",")
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values,new_activity__title__in=new_activity_values,
                                          tour_type__in=tour_type_values)
            else:
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values,
                                              new_activity__title__in=new_activity_values)
        else:
            return Package.objects.filter(new_activity__title__in=new_activity_values)
    elif destination is not None:
        destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", "")
        destination_values = destination.split(",")
        if new_activity is not None:
            new_activity = self.request.GET.get('new_activity', "")
            new_activity_values = new_activity.split(",")
            if tour_type is not None:
                tour_type = self.request.GET.get("tour_type", "")
                tour_type_values = tour_type.split(",")
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values,
                                              new_activity__title__in=new_activity_values,
                                              tour_type__in=tour_type_values)
            else:
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values,
                                              new_activity__title__in=new_activity_values
                                              )
        else:
            return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values)
    elif tour_type is not None:
        tour_type = self.request.GET.get("tour_type", "")
        tour_type_values = tour_type.split(",")
        if destination is not None:
            destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", "")
            destination_values = destination.split(",")
            if new_activity is not None:
                new_activity = self.request.GET.get('new_activity', "")
                new_activity_values = new_activity.split(",")
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values,
                                              new_activity__title__in=new_activity_values,
                                              tour_type__in=tour_type_values)
            else:
                return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in=destination_values,
                                                       tour_type__in=tour_type_values)
        else:
            return Package.objects.filter(tour_type__in=tour_type_values)
    else:
        return Package.objects.all()
```

This works as a filter for checkbox searches in ecommerce website, but it has a problem. When calling API, it repeats some of the objects i.e. same package object in my case. If anyone can solve it, let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solved this question before, I've decided to get multiple values in URL by using split `,` character.

Example: URL: `localhost/api/allpackages?destination=Spain,Japan,Thailand....featured=true...`

```
destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", "")

destination_values = destination.split(",")
```

Sample code about filtering `first_name`, `last_name`, and multiple values of `username` in User model.

model.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    @property
    def full_name(self):
        """Custom full name method as a property"""
        return str(self.first_name) + ' ' + str(self.last_name)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

view.py

```
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name']


class ListCreateUser(ListCreateAPIView):
    """
    List and Create User Generic contains create and list user APIs.
    """
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filterset_class = UserFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        username = self.request.GET.get('username', '')

        if username:
            username_values = username.split(',')
            return User.objects.filter(username__in=username_values)

        return User.objects.all()
```

Results:

- [image: List all users]
- [image: Filter by first_name, last_name, and username]
- Filter by username[image]

Comment: return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination) so this should be replaced with return Package.objects.filter(destination__name=destination_values)?? after writing above code??

Comment: Just correct your code is `return Package.objects.filter(destination__name__in= destination_values)`. This is a way when using `__in`.
Or Q object to implement OR condition (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)

Comment: I am getting this error 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. How to solve this? @vu Phan

Comment: |The main url ie localhost/api/allpackages. I havent put any parameters, yet it shows this error. How to solve it??

Comment: Got the error, because this `destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", [])`. Updated my answer: `destination = self.request.GET.get("destination", "")`

Comment: Hi Vu Phan, the error is removed but now the api is empty ie no data are shown. I have updated my view which you can see above.

Comment: Query filter is missing __in

Comment: It still doesnt work, i think its related with get_queryset(self), i think it cant be used with GET.get. Can you help @Vu Phan

Comment: Make sure the URL contains the param and value `localhost/api/allpackages?destination=Spain,Japan,Thailand`; make sure `destination` table has `Spain`,... It's not related to get_queryset(self), you can get the value of `destination` in that method or list() method.

Comment: I think this has a problem, if I have to only select localhost/api/allpackages?featured=true&tour_type=Group Tour, it doesnt return anything, I have to include destination parameter always. How can we recover this??

Comment: Seem your code does not includes handling code for ‘featured’ and ‘tour_type’ parameter.

Comment: You can override list method as well, make sure you cover all the case with every parameter.

Comment: No, I have packagefilter there if you can see, it includes featured and tour_type parameter. The problem i can search through featured= true but for that i have to include destination paramter in the url always, otherwise it doesnt work.

Comment: Got it, you right. It’s related to overriding get_queryset(), try to override list or get method as well.

Comment: when using get(self,request,*args,**kwargs), you have to return Response(serilaizer.data) which is not possible in my case.How to overwrite get or list and use my code??? do you have any idea?

Comment: I think package django_filter work based on returning get_queryset method. You should read the code base of django_filter first. The idea is query filter by the field “destination” based on returning result in django_filter. I’m sure.

Comment: Okay, I will remove PackageFilter and put every parameter of the filter inside get method, but if I have localhost/api/allpackages, it wont return anything, i have to include at least one parameter in the url.

Comment: Dont forget check “” or None value before using filter query.

Comment: How to do that? CaN you write the code for me??

Comment: I have updated my solution. Can you have a look at it? @Vu Phan

Comment: @Saroj Paudel Sad :( I will give a hand for coding the sample tonight

Comment: Ok let me know @Vu Phan

Comment: Just done, it works well with django-filter package. See the code in my answer.

Comment: The thing is as I said before, If I do your code, my api results will be empty if I didn't include query parameter username in your case (destination in my case). You dont need to include query parameters like first name that is coming from filter_class but you must include username in the query parameter. But, it will give the results if  I do it my way for eg using None before entering the if else statements. @Vu Phan

Answer (score 2):

I found that Django supports multi-value parameters with its [QueryDict](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict) since at least 3.0 . So when you have the situation like:

```
https://www.example.com/foo?a=1&a=2
```

you can get all values of `a` with:

```
def my_function(request):
    a_list = request.query_params.getlist('a')
    # [1, 2]
```

This is not intuitive, since `request.query_params.get('a')` only returns the **last** element in the list (see documentation).

Comment: can you please tell me what should be the **URL** for `https://www.example.com/foo?a=1&a=2` in `urls.py`

Comment: @AzharUddinSheikh: What about `urlpatterns = [path('foo', views.my_function, name='my_func')]`? This should hand over the request to the function `my_function` with the request as parameter. The `views.my_function` of course only applies, if `my_function` is defined in `views.py`.

Comment: This is the right answer, `self.request.query_params.getlist()` is available in django rest framework.

Answer (score 1):

[django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) does not provide multi-value filter support, you have to write it yourself if you want **OR** you can use [djangorestframework-jsonapi](https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/getting-started.html#installation) it provides the multi-value filter and many other pluggable features

> Membership in a list of values: ?filter[name.in]=abc,123,zzz (name in ['abc','123','zzz'])

You can configure the filter backends either by setting the REST_FRAMEWORK['DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS'] or individually add them as .filter_backends

```
'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': (
        'rest_framework_json_api.filters.QueryParameterValidationFilter',
        'rest_framework_json_api.filters.OrderingFilter',
        'rest_framework_json_api.django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend',
        'rest_framework.filters.SearchFilter',
    ),
```

See this example
https://django-rest-framework-json-api.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html#configuring-filter-backends

Your code with changes you don't need to write PackageFilter and  get_queryset

```
from rest_framework_json_api import django_filters

class AllPackageAPIView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Package.objects.all()
    serializer_class = PackageSerializer
    filter_backends = (django_filters.DjangoFilterBackend)
    filterset_fields = {'destination': ('exact', 'in'), ...}
```